# Image scaling error in chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari, transform

In my webpage I have a div with border-radius:50%; inside that div I have added an image, when hover on that image, it scales in to 1.2. this thing works properly in mozilla, but when I comes to chrome and safari, the image scales by overflowing it than the circular div (border-radius:50%), why this is happening. is there any method to solve this ?

***code***

**HTML**

```
<div class="work-round">
  <img src="images/latestwork_01.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.work-round {
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
}

.work-round img {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 240px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    width: 350px;
}
.work-round img:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

[fiddled here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/s0bpp0ho/)

screenshot on hover [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found by nickspiel here: [css3 border radius animation transition in safari not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475279/css3-border-radius-animation-transition-in-safari-not-working)

See:
https://jsfiddle.net/KyleKatarn/s0bpp0ho/6/

```
.work-round {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
```

To get partial support on Safari:
https://jsfiddle.net/KyleKatarn/s0bpp0ho/7/

Comment: New one tested OK on Chrome

Comment: works in chrome, and partially in safari, the border of outer div overlapped by image. can I solve that ?

Comment: Hum, the best I could: https://jsfiddle.net/s0bpp0ho/7/ See this post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202128/rounded-cornes-border-radius-safari-issue

Comment: anyway this is the most working answer, thanx dude :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution (tested on Chrome)

```
*{

    background:red;
}
.work-round {
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-height:250px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:250px;
    transition: all 2s linear;    
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white, black);


}

.work-round img {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 240px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    width: 350px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;width:100%;height:100%;

}
.work-round img:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code see results [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tz595q34/)

it chrome BUG with scale and overflow .

for the container that have the ( overflow:hidden )
add ( in your case its the .work-round )

```
position:relative;
z-index:1;
```