# Safari only, div background-image hover effect losing border-radius

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions

In Safari only, when I hover over `.panel-bg`, `.panel` loses its border-radius for a fraction of a second.

If I disable the rule `-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;` for `.panel-bg` this effect goes away.

Is there any solution so we can maintain the transition `.panel-bg:hover {transform: scale(1.03);}` without `.panel` losing its border-radius?

Help appreciated.

```css
.panel {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-size: contain;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px;
    transition: all .5s 0s ease;
}
.panel-bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    z-index: 0;
}
.panel-link {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.panel-bg:focus, .panel-bg:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
.panel-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<li class="panel">
  <div style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0), rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.7)), url('https://herodevelopment.com.au/allbathroomgear/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/laundry.jpg')" class="panel-bg"></div>
  <a href="#" title="Laundries" class="panel-link">
    <span class="panel-text">Laundries</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have been around forever.

Based on a fix provided in [css3 border radius animation transition in safari not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475279/css3-border-radius-animation-transition-in-safari-not-working) way back in 2013 by @nickspiel and altered only by noticing we don't need a prefix on radial gradients now if we add

```
-webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(white, black);
```

to the **parent** element this masks the corner so the image's transition 'corners' are not seen.

```css
.panel {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-size: contain;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px;
    transition: all .5s 0s ease;
    -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(white, black);/* ADDED */
}
.panel-bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    z-index: 0;
}
.panel-link {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.panel-bg:focus, .panel-bg:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
.panel-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<li class="panel">
  <div style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0), rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.7)), url('https://herodevelopment.com.au/allbathroomgear/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/laundry.jpg')" class="panel-bg"></div>
  <a href="#" title="Laundries" class="panel-link">
    <span class="panel-text">Laundries</span>
  </a>
</li>
```