# Border-radius not working properly on iOS - can't reproduce the issue on desktop

Tags: css

All thumbnails on my website have border-radius: 5px. The only problem I have is present on iOS (browser doesn't matter) - when images are loading, for a split second they are showing with border-radius: 0px then transitioning to border-radius 5px. Here are all the "phases" in right order:

1. screenshot1
2. screenshot2
3. screenshot3

Basically I want to get rid of phase two. I cannot reproduce the issue on desktop so I have no idea how can I fix it. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: This sounds like the same problem that was fixed in [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66269471/safari-only-div-background-image-hover-effect-losing-border-radius/66274238#66274238 does that help?

Comment: I've been experiencing this regularly for the past year or so across plenty of sites on iOS. Seems to be an Apple issue.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes!!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell iOS is so problematic... Everything works great everywhere but not on iPhones.

Comment: @kacperrro99 did that solve your issue?

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell yes it did.